# How to get xmlrpc response from a mysql db like field-names as elements and records as data?

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, xml-parsing, xml-rpc

I am working with webservices using xmlrpc-epi for a PHP/MySQL based website, I am getting xmlrpc client respaonse like below:

```
opening socket to host: comingsoon.com, port: 80, uri: /CM_server.php
sending http request:
POST /CM_server.php HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: xmlrpc-epi-php/0.2 (PHP) 
Host: fn24dev.com:80 Content-Type: text/xml 
Content-Length: 117 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<methodCall> 
<methodName>listVideos</methodName> 
<params/> 
</methodCall>
receiving response...
got response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> 
<methodResponse> 
<params>
 <param>
  <value>
   <array>
    <data>
     <value>
      <struct>
       <member>
        <name>0</name>
         <value>
          <string>63</string>
         </value>
       </member>
       <member>
        <name>indexer</name>
         <value>
          <string>63</string>
         </value>
       </member>
       <member>
        <name>1</name>
        <value>
         <string>02_CHIMPPANTS_24-03-2012_04-43-06</string>
        </value>
       </member>
       <member>
        <name>video_id</name>
        <value>
         <string>02_CHIMPPANTS_24-03-2012_04-43-06</string>
        </value>
       </member>
       <member>
        <name>2</name>
        <value>
        <string>mp4</string>
        </value> </member>
      <member>
        <name>type</name>
        <value>
         <string>mp4</string>
        </value>
      </member>
     </struct>
   </value> 
  </data> 
  </array>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodResponse>
```

In this, I am getting both mysql table fieldnames and field values as xml text contents. But I want to get response like mysql fieldnames as element and field values as text content. like below,

```
<member>
       <indexer>63</indexer>
</member>

<member>
      <video_id>02_CHIMPPANTS_24-03-2012_04-43-06</video_id>
</member>
<member>
  <type>mp4</type>
</member>
```

I've added PHP code & mysql table and data for clarifications.

```
Table_name: videos
    indexer     video_id                           type
    --------       ----------------------------------  -----
    63          02_CHIMPPANTS_24-03-2012_04-43-06      mp4
    54          02_Friday_23-03-2012_05-11-18          mp4
```

**CM_server.php**

```
<?php
function Connect(){
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db = mysql_select_db("database") or die("Database is not valid");
}

//Get the Videos
function getVideos(){
//connect database
Connect();
$videoquery = mysql_query("select * from videos");
    if(mysql_num_rows($videoquery) == "0"){
        $returnquery = "0";
    } else {
        while($getquery = mysql_fetch_array($videoquery)){
            $returnquery[] = $getquery;
        }
    }
    return $returnquery;
}
//server creating and check a list a method
$request = $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA;
if (!$request) $request_xml = $HTTP_POST_VARS['xml'];
$server = xmlrpc_server_create( );
if (!$server) die("Couldn't create server");
xmlrpc_server_register_method($server, 'listVideos', 'getVideos');
$options = array('output_type' => 'xml', 'version' => 'auto');
echo xmlrpc_server_call_method($server, $request, null, $options);
xmlrpc_server_destroy($server);
?>
```

**client.php**

```
<?php
include("utils.php");
$options = array('output_type' => 'xml', 'version' => 'xmlrpc');
$result1 = xu_rpc_http_concise(array(method => 'listVideos',host  => 'comingsoon.com',uri=> '/CM_server.php',options => $options,debug => 1));
?>
```

**utils.php**

```
<?php
xu_load_extension();
// a function to ensure the xmlrpc extension is loaded.
// xmlrpc_epi_dir = directory where libxmlrpc.so.0 is located
// xmlrpc_php_dir = directory where xmlrpc-epi-php.so is located
function xu_load_extension($xmlrpc_php_dir="") {
   if(!extension_loaded('xmlrpc')) {
      $bSuccess = true;
      putenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/php4/apache/xmlrpc/");
      if ($xmlrpc_php_dir) {
         $xmlrpc_php_dir .= '/';
      }
      if (!extension_loaded("xmlrpc")) {
         $bSuccess = dl($xmlrpc_php_dir . "xmlrpc-epi-php.so");
      }
   }
   return $bSuccess;
}

/* generic function to call an http server with post method */
function xu_query_http_post($request, $host, $uri, $port, $debug, 
                            $timeout, $user, $pass, $secure=false) {
   $response_buf = "";
   if ($host && $uri && $port) {
      $content_len = strlen($request);

      $fsockopen = $secure ? "fsockopen_ssl" : "fsockopen";

      dbg1("opening socket to host: $host, port: $port, uri: $uri", $debug);
      $query_fd = $fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10);

      if ($query_fd) {

         $auth = "";
         if ($user) {
            $auth = "Authorization: Basic " .
                    base64_encode($user . ":" . $pass) . "\r\n";
         }

         $http_request = 
         "POST $uri HTTP/1.0\r\n" .
         "User-Agent: xmlrpc-epi-php/0.2 (PHP)\r\n" .
         "Host: $host:$port\r\n" .
         $auth .
         "Content-Type: text/xml\r\n" .
         "Content-Length: $content_len\r\n" . 
         "\r\n" .
         $request;

         dbg1("sending http request:</h3> <xmp>\n$http_request\n</xmp>", $debug);

         fputs($query_fd, $http_request, strlen($http_request));

         dbg1("receiving response...", $debug);

         $header_parsed = false;

         $line = fgets($query_fd, 4096);
         while ($line) {
            if (!$header_parsed) {
               if ($line === "\r\n" || $line === "\n") {
                  $header_parsed = 1;
               }
               dbg2("got header - $line", $debug);
            }
            else {
               $response_buf .= $line;
            }
            $line = fgets($query_fd, 4096);
         }

         fclose($query_fd);
      }
      else {
         dbg1("socket open failed", $debug);
      }
   }
   else {
      dbg1("missing param(s)", $debug);
   }

   dbg1("got response:</h3>. <xmp>\n$response_buf\n</xmp>\n", $debug);

   return $response_buf;
}

function xu_fault_code($code, $string) {
   return array('faultCode' => $code,
                'faultString' => $string);
}


function find_and_decode_xml($buf, $debug) {
   if (strlen($buf)) {
      $xml_begin = substr($buf, strpos($buf, "<?xml"));
      if (strlen($xml_begin)) {

         $retval = xmlrpc_decode($xml_begin);
      }
      else {
         dbg1("xml start token not found", $debug);
      }
   }
   else {
      dbg1("no data", $debug);
   }
   return $retval;
}

function xu_rpc_http_concise($params) {
   $host = $uri = $port = $method = $args = $debug = null;
   $timeout = $user = $pass = $secure = $debug = null;

    extract($params);

    // default values
    if(!$port) {
        $port = 80;
    }
    if(!$uri) {
        $uri = '/';
    }
    if(!$output) {
        $output = array(version => 'xmlrpc');
    }

   $response_buf = "";
   if ($host && $uri && $port) {
      $request_xml = xmlrpc_encode_request($method, $args, $output);
      $response_buf = xu_query_http_post($request_xml, $host, $uri, $port, $debug,
                                         $timeout, $user, $pass, $secure);

      $retval = find_and_decode_xml($response_buf, $debug);
   }
   return $retval;
}

/* call an xmlrpc method on a remote http server. legacy support. */
function xu_rpc_http($method, $args, $host, $uri="/", $port=80, $debug=false, 
                     $timeout=0, $user=false, $pass=false, $secure=false) {
    return xu_rpc_http_concise(
        array(
            method  => $method,
            args    => $args,
            host    => $host,
            uri     => $uri,
            port    => $port,
            debug   => $debug,
            timeout => $timeout,
            user    => $user,
            pass    => $pass,
            secure  => $secure
        ));
}



function xu_is_fault($arg) {
   // xmlrpc extension finally supports this.
   return is_array($arg) ? xmlrpc_is_fault($arg) : false;
}

/* sets some http headers and prints xml */
function xu_server_send_http_response($xml) {
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    header("Content-length: " . strlen($xml) );
    echo $xml;
}


function dbg($msg) {
   echo "<h3>$msg</h3>"; flush();
}
function dbg1($msg, $debug_level) {
   if ($debug_level >= 1) {
      dbg($msg);
   }
}
function dbg2($msg, $debug_level) {
   if ($debug_level >= 2) {
      dbg($msg);
   }
}


?>
```

If anyone knows xmlrpc to get this solution please guide me.

Comment: I've added source code for more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you are asking for would not be XML-RPC, so you will not be able to achieve it using PHP's XML-RPC extension. The [XML-RPC Specification](http://xmlrpc.scripting.com/spec) defines a precise structure for responses, including the available types.

The kind of XML service you have in mind just needs an XML parsing library (e.g. SimpleXML), some XML creation functions (which could be a recursive function turning a PHP array into an XML-formatted string) and a small amount of "dispatching code" to support different methods on one URL:

```
$request_xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
$request_sx = simplexml_load_string($request_xml);
switch ( (string)$request_sx->Method )
{
    case 'listVideos':
        $data = getVideos( (string)$request_sx->Params->SearchTerm );
        $response_xml = generate_xml($data);
    break;
}

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $response_xml;
exit;
```